# Cassandra as Cache Front-end to RDBMS

Tags: oracle, caching, cassandra

We are using Oracle RDBMS in our system. To reduce database load we plan to use a caching layer.

I am looking to see if we can use Apache Cassandra as a Caching Storage frontend to Oracle db.

From what I have looked so far Cassandra is more like a database with built-in caching features. So, using it as a caching layer to Oracle would be more like using another database. I feel it would be better to Cassandra itself as an alternative to Oracle and other RDBMS rather than using it along with Oracle.

Has anyone used Cassandra as a caching layer to RDBMS. But, I have not found any resources or examples for using it. If so can you help me on this.

Comment: If you need a cache why not just use a cache?

Comment: Yes. I am looking to use cassandra as a cache for the RDBMS. But not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Cassandra isn't a cache, it's a persisted log storage database. You probably want a Redis, or memcache

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by a caching storage frontend.

Cassandra might be useful if you are expecting a large volume of writes that arrive at a rate faster than Oracle could handle.  Cassandra can handle a high volume of writes since it can scale by adding more nodes.

You could then do some kind of data analysis and reduction on the data in Cassandra before inserting the crunched data into Oracle.  You might then use Oracle for the tasks that suit it better such as financial reporting, ad hoc queries, etc.